# How to prove a function bounded on an interval?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\alpha $ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)=\beta$

show, using the definition of the limit, that there is an interval of the form $[M, \infty)$
on which $f$ is bounded and that $\lim{}_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)g(x) =\alpha\beta$

Comment: What did you try and what did you learn?

Answer (score 0):

Remember what $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\alpha$ means:

> For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $M=M_\varepsilon$ such that, for every $x\geq M$, $|f(x)-\alpha|<\varepsilon$.

What happens if you use that with, say, $\varepsilon=1$? Then, prove and use the inequality
$$|f(x)g(x)-\alpha\beta|\leq|f(x)||g(x)-\beta|+|f(x)-\alpha||\beta|,\quad\forall x$$
along with the boundedness of $f$ in $[M,\infty)$ to prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)g(x)=\alpha\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $r>0$ to be fixed later.

1. $f$ is bounded: take $\epsilon= 1$ in the definition of the limit. It gives an $M$ such as 
   $$x\ge M\implies |f(x)-\alpha|\le 1
   \\
   \implies |f(x)|\le |f(x)-\alpha|+|\alpha|
   \le 1+|\alpha|.$$
2. Now consider $f(x)g(x)-\alpha\beta = f(x)(g(x)-\beta) + (f(x)-\alpha)\beta
   $.
   $$x\ge M\implies
   |f(x)g(x)-\alpha\beta|
   \le 
   |f(x)||g(x)-\beta| + |f(x)-\alpha||\beta|\\
   \le (1+|\alpha|)|g(x)-\beta|+|f(x)-\alpha||\beta|
   $$Now use the fact that $f(x)\to\alpha$ and $g(x)\to\beta$:
   $$
   \exists M'>M\ \ \ x\ge M'\implies
   \max(|g(x)-\beta|,|f(x)-\alpha|)\le r
   \\
   \implies |f(x)||g(x)-\beta| + |f(x)-\alpha||\beta|
   \le (1+|\alpha|+|\beta|)r\le \epsilon
   $$
   if you choose $r=\frac \epsilon{1+|\alpha|+|\beta|}$.